# How does one access HTML Canvas elements in Opa?

Tags: opa

Is it possible to access HTML5 canvas elements in Opa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible to access HTML5 canvas elements in Opa!

See the online API doc:
http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#canvas.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.xhtml.Canvas

And you know what? Hhuho pushed on github a collaborative whiteboard based on html5 canvas:
https://github.com/hhugo/OpaWhiteBoard

You can play with it here: http://canvas.opalang.org/

Comment: It's still served as XHTML 1.1 :-(